# Insert List of tupels in mysql Db using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am trying to insert a list of tuples with numbers which I got from a csv file, into my MySQL DB.

Code I have:

```
readcsv = pd.read_csv( "***********************.csv", skiprows=45, sep=";")
cols = str(readcsv.columns.values.tolist()).replace('[','').replace(']', '').replace('\'','`')
for i in range(0, readcsv.shape[0], 1):
    values = str(readcsv.iloc[i:i+1].values.tolist()).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')').replace('((', '(').replace('))', ')')


print(values)

conn = pymysql.connect(host='****', port=3306, user='root', passwd='*****', db='***')

cursor = conn.cursor()
rows = [values]

a = ','.join(map(str ,rows))
b = ','.join(map(str ,rows))
c =','.join(map(str ,rows))
d =','.join(map(str ,rows))

sql = "INSERT INTO csv_files.csv_file(ms, Power_in_W,Distance_in_mm,Force_in_N) VALUES ({},{},{},{})".format(a,b,c,d)

cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I already created a db in mySQL with the colums MS, Power_in_W, Distance_in_mm, Force_in_N. But somehow I cannot insert the data from the csv into it. Because of the error :

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1
>   column(s)')

Output I get with `print(values)` is:

```
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (2.0, 60.3, 960.0, 0.0), (3.0, 60.3, 964.0,0.0), (4.0, 60.3, 967.0, 0.0), (5.0, 61.89, 964.0, 0.0), (6.0, 61.89, 967.0, 0.0), (7.0, 13.69, 962.0, 0.0)
```

...

Does anyone knows what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Not the main question point here but be careful with string formatting in database queries to avoid sql injections. https://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0):

use the [execute_many](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.executemany) method, and pass values as parameter.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO csv_files.csv_file(ms, Power_in_W,Distance_in_mm,Force_in_N) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"

cursor.executemany(sql, values)
```

Comment: now i got another Traceback: 
TypeError: not enough Arguments for Format string

Comment: values should be sequence of sequence, can you just read values into some list, other than str?

Comment: sorry i do not understand what you mean with "read values into some list,other than str?"

Answer (score 0):

Got it. - Problem solved. 
only used Parameter a , changed the size of my MS value and last but not least i put everything into the for-loop.